# python: looking to save attachments from outlook mail received Today and with specific subject

Tags: python, outlook

How can include 'today' variable in variable 'myMail' which will include only those objects(mails) with specific sender as well as time(mails received today)
    import win32com.client
    import os
    from win32com.client import Dispatch
    import datetime as dt

```
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
root_folder = outlook.Folders.Item(1)


today = dt.date.today()


for folder in root_folder.Folders:

   myfolder = root_folder.Folders['Daily Input Files']

Filter = "[SenderEmailAddress] = 'indices@nse.co.in'"
myMail = myfolder.Items.Restrict(Filter)

  Item = myMail.GetFirst()
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar requirement of downloading attachment from Outlook emails.

Here is how I worked on the solution: https://medium.com/@theamazingexposure/accessing-shared-mailbox-using-exchangelib-python-f020e71a96ab

A python library called exchangelib worked for me: https://pypi.org/project/exchangelib/

Here is the snippet from my code to download attachment:

```
for attachment in item.attachments:
    if isinstance(attachment, FileAttachment):
        filepath = os.path.join('C:\\path\\to\\your\\directory', attachment.name)
```